# Setting the generic type param to object by default c#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

Given a method:

```
private static T GetBin<T>(string file)
```

Is it possible to set T to default to `object`, if I use:

```
public static byte[] ToJSONBytes<T>(this T obj)
```

It defaults to whatever `obj` is set as. However, this GetBin method Deserializes a file, using the BinaryFormatter, and as you all know, it returns an object. My method explicitly casts it to T and then returns it, but I want to make T optional and default to `object`.

Comment: Then why not just return `object` and let the caller cast it if they want to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generic type parameters cannot have default values.

However, they can have overloads:

```
private static object GetBin(string file) { return GetBin<object>(file); }
```

Comment: But generic arguments aren't part of the signature, so that won't compile due to ambiguity errors, no?

Comment: @Servy: Compiles fine in LINQPad, just tested it.

Comment: @Servy: Generic overloading ((like this) does work.  You're thinking of overload _resolution_ with constraints; http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx.